# grep for variable pattern: echo "${foo}" | grep "'${bar}'"

Tags: grep

I will need to grep one variable for a variable pattern.

Like so

```
foo="--test2"
bar="--test"
echo "${foo}" | grep "'${bar}'"
```

Unfortunately it is not working.

Any ideas about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use , single quotes it will take it as literal string. Remove the single quotes. Then it will throw the error for `--` in your string. For that use `-e` option for mention that is a pattern to match.

```
echo "${foo}" | grep -e "${bar}"
```

Answer (score 1):

your pattern is leading with `-`,  `-e` option is needed.

this line should work for your example:

```
 echo "${foo}" | grep -e "${bar}"
```

Comment: Thanks you too. Same answer with same working state. Karthikeyan.R.S was just a minute faster, so i marked his answer as correct. Yours is as well.

Comment: @lockdoc what important is, your problem gets sovled. it is ok which answer was accepted. but you should change the word `faster` in your above comment into `slower`. :-)

Comment: Ohh sorry, I totally misinterpreted the time display. *///* my bad.